# What happens when an electron hits its maximum energy level?

Tags: energy, electrons, atoms

Does it break free from the atom? I'm in 8th Grade, and just came across this question on my Physical Science homework.

Answer (score 3):

Informally: yes, the electron will break free from the atom, leaving behind a positively-charged ion.

Formally, though: no, there are no "maximum energy levels" in atoms. Atoms have an infinite sequence of energy levels, known as their Rydberg series, and for any given state it is always possible to find another state with even higher energy.

However, these energies do have an upper bound, and they cluster ever-closer together as you go up and up the ladder:

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Image source](https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/handle/1811/46079)</sup>

In other words:

- There isn't a bound state with a maximal energy, but
- there *is* a maximal amount of energy that the atom can have while remaining bound.

If you supply more energy than that, the atom will fall apart, by releasing one electron which will then be free ('ionized') to wander off at will.

Answer (score 2):

It will 'break free' from the atom, leaving the atom with a net positive charge. The charged atom is then called an *ion*, and the process is called *ionisation*. Different atoms also have different ionisation energies, depending on their electron configuration.